# Difference between MySQL workbench and mysql-connector-java-5.1.15

Tags: mysql, ant, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run the following sql script on a mysql server through an ant task using mysql-connector-java-5.1.15, but it will not work and I get the following error on the third command. I can get other scripts to work OK from ant so it is not a connection problem.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF 
EXISTS `tmp_cui_desc`;
CREATE TABLE `tmp_cui_desc` (
    CUI CHAR(8' at line 15
```

Strangely the script works absolutely fine in a MySql workbench (v5.2.31) connected to the same server. Why should that be? The database is latin1 and the character-set-system is uft8. Could this be part of the problem? If so what do I need to do to fix it?

Hugely grateful for any help
Rob.

```
USE umls;

/*
 * creates a summary view of the umls_mrconso table which abstracts most of the detail from atoms to concepts
 * this is a table with a single row per CUI
 * 
 */

/*
 * Create a temporary table based on the sources of a given cui
 */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_cui_sabs;
CREATE TABLE tmp_cui_sabs (
    CUI CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    SABS VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (CUI)
)
SELECT 
    u.CUI as CUI, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.SAB ORDER BY u.SAB ASC SEPARATOR '|') as SABS
FROM umls_mrconso u 
GROUP BY u.CUI;

/* 
 * Create a temporary table containing the best available description for any given cui
 */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_cui_desc;
CREATE TABLE tmp_cui_desc (
    CUI CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    TERM VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (CUI)
)
SELECT 
    u.CUI as CUI, 
    MIN(u.STR) as TERM 
FROM umls_mrconso u 
WHERE u.ISPREF='Y' 
AND u.LAT='ENG' 
AND u.TS='P' 
GROUP BY u.CUI;

/*
 * Create a permanent table as the join of the 2 temporary tables
 * contains a preferred description, and all the sources that map to this cui,
 * as well as the CUI itself.
 * TODO: could be useful to include semantic type info here as well?
 */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bmj_cui_summary;
CREATE TABLE bmj_cui_summary (
    CUI CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    TERM VARCHAR(255), 
    SABS VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (CUI)
)
SELECT 
    sabs.CUI as CUI, 
    LOWER(descs.TERM) as TERM, 
    sabs.SABS as SABS 
FROM 
    tmp_cui_sabs sabs, 
    tmp_cui_desc descs 
WHERE sabs.CUI=descs.CUI;

/*
 * clean up tmp tables
 */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_cui_sabs;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_cui_desc;
```

Comment: dont know about jdbc, but normaly you can only comit one sql statement at the time via the c-lib. (which i guess is used by jdbc too). if you use ant, cant you call the mysql client directly. e.g. `mysql -uusername -ppassword < sqlfile.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you probably can only send one command per query. So separate them by the ; and query individually. I got this problem in a different language.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to send more than one command, but the jdbc engine does some query parsing before submitting. In this event it didn't like the \*  *\ comment style, and it worked once replaced with # syntax